# Audio Spectrum Effect iOS/Android

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios, audio

I'm wondering if there is any way to get an audio effect like the one [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWNnBpuZMuI&feature=plcp&context=C4fa98fdVDvjVQa1PpcFNfPjU4bg9M-7EQuFCJBJ8NdC8hL11KSog=)
in Java and/or Objective C. It is normally done in After Effects, but I want to create it on a smartphone. I know that the x axis is frequency and the y axis is volume. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at [`Visualizer.getFft(byte[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#getFft%28byte[]%29)?

Comment: I'm trying to use the BASS Library on a Mac and it wont compile because of a error "executable not found"

Comment: The Bass Audio Library-Google it. Also, I posted the previous question as a subquestion.

Comment: Disregard anything I said before. Is there a Visualizer.getFft equivalent on ios?

Comment: Sorry, only just starting with Android.  Never worked with iOS.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about iOS, but if you don't mind the extra space, Eclipse can handle a .mp3 file, and you can play it using the MediaPlayer class. As for creating the file, I'm not sure .raw has enough distinct sounds.

I played an mp3 in Android using a separate Music.java class and then calling it with mp3s in res/raw/*.mp3

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Music
{
private static MediaPlayer mp = null;

//Stop old song, play new one
public static void play(Context context, int resource)
{
    stop(context);


    if (Prefs.isMusic(context)) //is music on?
    {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resource);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }//end if
}//end play method

//Stop the music
public static void stop(Context context)
{
    if(mp != null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }//end if
}//end stop method
}//end class Music
```

and the calls in my Game.java file:

```
Music.play(this, R.raw.game);
Music.stop(this);
```

Comment: i didn't mean creating the file, i meant to create the effect. im going to need a fft library and a way of drawing the "bars" on screen